# Spring-boot mongodb - how to convert MongoRepository save response to custom class and return as JSON

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I'm trying to learn `spring-boot` with `mongodb`. I've followed online articles and tutorials and the sample application is working fine for returning string as API response. But when I'm trying to return response as JSON using `ResponseEntity` I'm getting an error.

Here's the code:

`src/customerapi/model/Customer.java`

```
package com.customerapi.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString

@Document(collation = "customer")
public class Customer {
    @Id
    private String custRefId;
    
    private String title;

    private String firstName;
    
    private String middleName;

    private String lastName;
    
    private String businessName;

    private String email;

    private String phone;

    private String note;
    
    private String dateOfBirth;

    private String sex;
    
    
}
```

`src/customerapi/dto/CustomerResponse.java`

```
package com.customerapi.dto;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude.Include;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class CustomerResponse {
    @JsonProperty("custRefId")
    private String custRefId;
    
}
```

`src/customerapi/repository/CustomerRepository.java`

```
package com.customerapi.repository;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import com.customerapi.dto.CustomerResponse;
import com.customerapi.model.Customer;

public interface CustomerRepository extends MongoRepository<Customer, String> {
}
```

`src/customerapi/resource/CustomerController.java`

```
package com.customerapi.resource;

import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.customerapi.repository.CustomerRepository;
import com.customerapi.model.Customer;
import com.customerapi.dto.CustomerResponse;

@RestController
public class CustomerController {
    
    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepository customerRepository;
    
    @PostMapping(value="/addCustomer", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse> saveCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse>(new customerRepository.save(customer), HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }finally {
            System.out.println("Issue with saving data in DB");
        }
    }
}
```

Returning a `string` from `saveCustomer()` works fine. But when I'm trying to return `ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse>` and hit the endpoint in Postman I'm getting this error.

[image: postman error]

I searched online and tried multiple things from stackoverflow answers but nothing seems to be working for me.

**How do I convert `MongoRepository`'s `save` response to custom class and return as JSON using `ResponseEntity`? **

Comment: The error says that u dont have constructor. Create `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@AllArgsConstructor` in CustomerResponse

Comment: @varman Adding a constructor as suggested in below answer helped me to resolve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `new CustomerResponse(customerRepository.save(customer))`.  Inside `CustomerResponse` there is no constructor which accepts `Customer` as a parameter. You can create one. So your `CustomerResponse`  would look like this.

```
import com.customerapi.model.Customer;

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public class CustomerResponse {
    @JsonProperty("custRefId")
    private String custRefId;
    
    public CustomerResponse(Customer customer){
        this.custRefId = customer.getCustRefId();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Valay you what `Customer` object in return or just `custRefId`?

Comment: I've updated the code in `CustomerController.java` to `return new ResponseEntity<CustomerResponse>(new customerRepository.save(customer), HttpStatus.CREATED);`. I tried with the approach you suggested but still getting the same error.

Comment: Update code in `CustomerResponse`. Not `CustomerController`

Comment: Yes I've updated the code in `CustomerResponse` as suggested. In question description I've updated `CustomerController`.  The error remains same.

Comment: Sorry it was my mistake to remove `new CustomerResponse` from `ResponseEntity` statement. It's working now. Thanks.